# WP get posts with custom post format from every category

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I'm trying to get posts from all categories but with one post format, the post format named homePost, I just a beginner in WordPress and I just finished learning the front-end developing and PHP+MySQL developing and I need your help guys :)

### Here is my code

```
<?php $args = array( 'orderby' => 'name', 'parent' => 0 );
$categories = get_categories( $args );
foreach ( $categories as $category ) {

$homePosts = array(
'post_type'=> 'post',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'category'         => $category->cat_ID,
'order' => 'DESC',
'tax_query' => array(
     array(
    'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
    'field' => 'slug',
    'terms' => array( 'homePost' )
    )
    )
);

    $asides = get_posts( $homePosts );
    if ( count($asides) ) {
        foreach ( $asides as $homePosts ) {
            '<p>' + 'Test' + '</p>' ;
        }
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: Can you tell us if you see any *Error Messages*  or notices first, or go into details as to what is not properly working? Also it seems this code could be prone to generate duplicate post when displayed since users can select multiple categories for the same post. Also if you didnt have it already activated you can place `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` in your **wp-config.php** file.

Comment: my problem is there is nothing in the page (not showing any error also), i made a custom page template to add this code in and it's not showing any thing, i have tried using `WP_Query` and it's still not working, i need to display all categories and there posts under theme but i need to show only the posts with a costume format

Answer (score 0):

Hi create a PHP file in the same theme and name your name in it

```
<?php
        /*
        Template Name: Contact Us
        */
?>
```

And in admin panel pages in the right hand side there will be like template jus select the template name from the drop down